# Place a logo in Magento

Tags: html, css, xml, magento-1.9

I am working over a custom module of Magento, in which I want to place a logo in config->sales->payment methods->module. This is a place where I want to add a logo.

[image: This]

I tried using `CDATA`, but was not able to implement it correctly. Can somebody help me with this? Give a code which I will have to add with a label tag in system.xml file.

Comment: click on "This" above question to see the image.Please.Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<newgengiropay translate="label comment" module="newgengiropay">
    <label>
        <![CDATA[
            <div style="position:absolute;">
                <img id="newgengiropay_block" src="" alt="" border="0" />
                <span style="display:inline;position:absolute;right:0px; ">Giropay</span>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <script>$('newgengiropay_block').src = SKIN_URL + "images/newgengiropay/newgen.png";</script>
        ]]>
    </label>
</newgengiropay>
```

Comment: got my answer guys, you can check it out.